# Move path onkeydown

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am trying to move a path.Circle on keydown in paperjs but it doesn't work and I can't spot the mistake.

Here is the code and [this](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) is link to the sketch.

```
var rect = new Path.Rectangle({
  point: [0, 0],
  size: [view.size.width, view.size.height],
  strokeColor: 'white',
  selected: true
});

rect.sendToBack();
rect.fillColor = 'blue';

var beach = new Path.Rectangle({
  point: [0, 0],
  size: [view.size.width, view.size.height / 5],
  strokeColor: 'white',
  selected: true
});

beach.fillColor = "yellow";

var boat = new Path.Circle(new Point(xpoint, ypoint), 30);
boat.fillColor = "black";

xpoint = 100;
ypoint = 300;

function onKeyDown(event) {
  if (event.key == 'a') {
    xpoint -= 10;
  }

  if (event.key == 'd') {
    xpoint += 10;
  }

  if (event.key == 'w') {
    ypoint -= 10;
  }

  if (event.key == 's') {
    ypoint += 10;
  }
}
```

Comment: So you're just setting / incrementing the variable values on keydown. What are you triggering to redraw the path?

Comment: well that's how I clearly don't know how to do. Any hints?

Comment: I thought you would realize you weren't redrawing the boat with my question. See Sam Fen's answer for a detailed explanation. You need to draw the boat again with the new point values after they are changed.

Comment: Well I suspected that was the issue but couldn't figure out how to do it :) Thanks :)

Comment: @Naomi For what it's worth, I think that's partly the fault of PaperJS. I don't know PaperJS well, but it seems to do a fair bit of "magic" in terms of keeping the inner-workings of rendering to the screen and other stuff hidden from you. For this reason I'd say it's not clear to a newcomer why changing the properties of an object (without explicitly repainting) would cause a repaint, while changing the variable `xpoint` wouldn't. But for the actual reason why changing a numeric variable *couldn't* have worked, research "Javascript pass by value", and recall that a number is a primitive type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just setting the values of the variables that you originally used in creating the boat, but it's not changing the boat at all.

```
var x = 10,
    y = 10,
    boat = new Boat(x, y);    //pseudocode

// now setting x doesn't do anything at all. The value was already
// passed to boat, boat doesn't retain a reference to x 
x = 20;
```

Instead, change the variable and then modify boat directly. I don't know paperjs well, but the following seems to work:

```
function onKeyDown(event) {
   if(event.key == 'a') {
      xpoint -= 10;
   }
   // ...

   boat.setPosition(xpoint, ypoint)
}
```

Comment: FWIW: You can also use `boat.position = new Point(xpoint, ypoint)` or `boat.position += new Point(xOffset, yOffset)` See the docs for more: http://paperjs.org/tutorials/project-items/transforming-items/